# Django: decorator for catching response context from classic views

Tags: django, python-decorators

I have simple classic Django view:

```
@log_me
def single(request):
    item = Items.objects.all()[0]
    return render_to_response('ololo.html', {'object': item})
```

How can i catch context in `@log_me` decorator? I need this: `{'object': item}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.  `render_to_response` will render the template with the context and return a completed `HttpResponse` object.  The `HttpResponse` object would be available in your view decorator but the context data is already rendered into the response.

You'll need to think of another approach. A custom middleware may be an option, take a look at [`process_template_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response).